# how to select value from spinner android and then insert to mysql?

Tags: java, android, mysql

how to select value from spinner and then insert to php mysql?
I have two java files.

1.spinner

2.insert data to mysql

how to merge two files??

This is my java code any body help me?

1. spinner.java

   ```
   public class spinner extends Activity
   implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
   TextView selection;
   String[] items={"Aceh", "Sumatera Utara","Papua"};

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

       Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

       ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);

       aa.setDropDownViewResource(
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spin.setAdapter(aa);
   }

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                                               View v, int position, long id) {
       selection.setText(items[position]);
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       selection.setText("");
   }
   ```

   }
2. this file tambah_user.java

This is my file `tambah_user.java` code to send mysql amy body help me?

```
public class pasang extends Activity {
EditText nomor_reg, nama, ttl, jam, peruntukan, keterangan, notelp;
TextView status, myLatitude, myLongitude;
Button btnShowLocation, simpan, keluar;
GPSTracker gps;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pasang);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    // show location button click event
    myLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
    myLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
    nomor_reg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnomor_reg);
    nama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnama);
    ttl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtttl);
    jam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtjam);
    peruntukan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtperuntukan);
    keterangan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtketerangan);
    notelp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnotelp);
    simpan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsimpan);
    keluar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexit);
    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
    simpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nomor_reg",
                    nomor_reg.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", nama
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ttl", ttl.getText()
                    .toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jam", jam.getText()
                    .toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("peruntukan",
                    peruntukan.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keterangan",
                    keterangan.getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notelp", notelp
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", myLatitude
                    .getText().toString()));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", myLongitude
                    .getText().toString()));

            /* String valid = "1"; */

            String response = null;

            try {

                response = koneksigangguan.executeHttpPost(
                        "http://plnskh.zz.mu/android/lapor/pasang.php",
                        postParameters);

                String res = response.toString();

                res = res.trim();

                res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                status.setText(res);

                if (res.equals("1"))
                    status.setText("Data tidak Tersimpan Ke server");

                else
                    status.setText("Data berhasil disimpan ke server");

            }

            catch (Exception e) {

                nomor_reg.setText(e.toString());

            }

        }

    });
}

public void keluar(View theButton) {
    Intent a = new Intent(this, Mainmenu.class);
    startActivity(a);
    finish();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("YourParameter",mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.selectstate);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        String classval = item.toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: here classval is the value of spinner